# MySQL performance Issues while using INET_ATON

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a MySQL query

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE INET_ATON("10.0.0.1") BETWEEN INET_ATON(s_ip) AND INET_ATON(e_ip);
```

Here "10.0.0.1" comes dynamically when a user visits the website and s_ip is the starting ip address column which would probably have "10.0.0.0" as starting ip address range and e_ip is the ending IP address.

Now, the problem is I have almost ~350K records which do only one thing when this query is executed and that is to get me the country code of the visitor.

When this query is executed MySQL peaks CPU consumption at 1100% and multiply that by 1000 requests/minute and my server just cannot handle it.

My server is running CentOS 7 with 100 GB of RAM and 24 Cores clocked at 3.0 GHz but still the performance is becoming a nightmare for me to handle.

I was thinking of outsourcing this functionality to third party service but I just want to make sure that nothing can be done from my side to fix this issue.

(From Comments)

```
CREATE TABLE ip` (
    ip_ip varbinary(16) NOT NULL, 
    ip_last_request_time timestamp(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL, 
    ip_min_timeSpan_get smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL, 
    ip_min_timeSpan_post smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL, 
    ip_violationsCount_get smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL, 
    ip_violationsCount_post smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL, 
    ip_maxViolations_get smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL, 
    ip_maxViolations_post smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL, 
    ip_bannedAt timestamp(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    ip_banSeconds mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '300', 
    ip_isCapatchaResolved tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
    ip_isManualBanned tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
    ip_city varchar(45) DEFAULT '', 
    ip_region varchar(45) DEFAULT '', 
    ip_regionCode varchar(5) DEFAULT '', 
    ip_regionName varchar(45) DEFAULT '', 
    ip_countryCode varchar(3) DEFAULT '', 
    ip_countryName varchar(45) DEFAULT '', 
    ip_continentCode varchar(3) DEFAULT '', 
    ip_continentName varchar(45) DEFAULT '', 
    ip_timezone varchar(45) DEFAULT '', 
    ip_currencyCode varchar(4) DEFAULT '', 
    ip_currencySymbol_UTF8 varchar(5) DEFAULT '', 
    PRIMARY KEY (ip_ip), 
    KEY countryCode_index (ip_countryCode)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4`

CREATE TABLE country` ( co_id char(2) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL, 
    co_re_id smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL, 
    co_flag_id char(4) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL, 
    co_english_name varchar(40) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (co_id), 
    KEY fk_country_region1_idx (co_re_id), 
    CONSTRAINT fk_country_region1 FOREIGN KEY (co_re_id)
              REFERENCES region (re_id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Show table structure, some example data and explain output..

Comment: I have table IP which has(ip PK, countryCode, ...) and table country which has (countryCode PK, countryName, countryFlagCode, countryCurrency, ...) with this schema and the PK index on the IP column you can scale and query the Your IPs  without performance issues, just make sure the optimizer is using the index on the IP when you select based on IP

Comment: If you are selecting from countries table which has 195 records you shouldn't have performance issues (however, you should optimize as suggested by Joni Answer). But if you are selecting from the IPs table then what `s_ip` and `e_ip` do mean in IPs table, as Raymond Nijland said, please show the table structure, some data and explain what are you trying to do

Comment: @Accountantم - Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; there can be subtle issues that are missing from that brief description.

Comment: @RickJames ip table(1 of 3) `CREATE TABLE `ip` (
  `ip_ip` varbinary(16) NOT NULL,
  `ip_last_request_time` timestamp(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip_min_timeSpan_get` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ip_min_timeSpan_post` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ip_violationsCount_get` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ip_violationsCount_post` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ip_maxViolations_get` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ip_maxViolations_post` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ip_bannedAt` timestamp(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL,`

Comment: @RickJames ip table (2 of 3) `  `ip_banSeconds` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '300',
  `ip_isCapatchaResolved` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ip_isManualBanned` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ip_city` varchar(45) DEFAULT '',
  `ip_region` varchar(45) DEFAULT '',
  `ip_regionCode` varchar(5) DEFAULT '',
  `ip_regionName` varchar(45) DEFAULT '',
  `ip_countryCode` varchar(3) DEFAULT '',
  `ip_countryName` varchar(45) DEFAULT '',
`

Comment: @RickJames ip table (3of 3) `  `ip_continentCode` varchar(3) DEFAULT '',
  `ip_continentName` varchar(45) DEFAULT '',
  `ip_timezone` varchar(45) DEFAULT '',
  `ip_currencyCode` varchar(4) DEFAULT '',
  `ip_currencySymbol_UTF8` varchar(5) DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ip_ip`),
  KEY `countryCode_index` (`ip_countryCode`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4``

Comment: @RickJames country table `CREATE TABLE `country` (
  `co_id` char(2) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `co_re_id` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `co_flag_id` char(4) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `co_english_name` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`co_id`),
  KEY `fk_country_region1_idx` (`co_re_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_country_region1` FOREIGN KEY (`co_re_id`) REFERENCES `region` (`re_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci`

Comment: `10.x.y.z` is "private" space -- _anyone_ in _any country_ can have _all_ those IP addresses.  See, for example, [_here_](https://www.quora.com/Can-we-use-IPs-that-start-with-192-or-10-or-172-as-a-Public-IP-on-the-internet)

Answer (score 2):

Currently you're doing a full table scan for every query. There are a couple of things you can try.

- Store INET_ATON(s_ip) in the table so it's not computed during the query. Same for e_ip.
- Add an index that has these two new columns, and the country code.
- Change the query to select **only** the country code, and use the two new columns.

Use EXPLAIN to make sure the DB uses the index for the query.

Comment: The computation of `INET_ATON` is insignificant compared to the table scan.

Comment: Indeed, the main problem is that it prevents any use of an index.

Comment: Doing the `ATON` and storing into `BINARY(4)` is a great idea, but it is only one step.  (And, for IPv6, you need `BINARY(16)`.)

Answer (score 2):

The optimizer does not know that you have a set of non-overlapping ranges that it could do some optimizations based on it.  So, you have work harder to optimize the queries.

Instead of doing table scans, the code described [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ipranges) will do typical queries 'instantly'.

To put it bluntly, you cannot optimize the query without restructuring the data.  I'm speaking also to all who have provided Answers and Comments.

(critique of schema)

`ip` is awfully bulky.  Suggest moving `city` and all the fields after it to another table in order to 'normalize' that data.

It is 'wrong' to have both a `..code` and `..name` in the same table (except for the normalization table).

Several fields can (and should) be ascii, not utf8mb4.  Example: countryCode.

On another topic...  How will you handle AOL IP addresses?  As I understand it, these are shared among its customers.  That is, a "violator" will move around, tainting all of the AOL IPs.

10., 11., 172.16., 192.168.  all come from behind a NAT, and cannot be associated with a given country, nor a given computer.

Comment: "To put it bluntly, you cannot optimize the query without restructuring the data. I'm speaking also to all who have provided Answers and Comments." Well we tryed to give "good" answers without table structures

Comment: I know the document is old but "The datatype for the 'address' in the table must be ordered, and should be as compact as possible." That optimizalisation has a pretty big downside that would "wast" alot TB's of storage if you need the complete IPv4 and IPV6 ranges besides MySQLs 8,0 histogram might help out here if the optimizer is seeing non overlapping data is used.

Comment: @RaymondNijland - If it is primarily to map _IP ranges_ to countries, you need only a few hundred, or perhaps a few thousand ranges.  (And my link depends on that.)  But, it turns out that having _both_ 'start' and 'end' in each row hurts rather than helps.  My algorithm will map an IP to a country in one fetch of one row, even if the table is terabytes.

Comment: Thank you very much Rick James for your valued critique I'm finding them very useful. Yes the geographic data in the IP needs to get moved from the IPs table(normalized), but right now I just want things to get working as fast as I can and I will do this optimize later when I start to have very large IPs table(I have only about 5000 IPs now)

Comment: Regarding the violation, banning fields, I use them in PHP to protect myself from fast continues requests from the same IP(possibly a bot) and each IP has it's own rules (If an IP belongs to huge network that many clients are using the same IP in, I can change the rules for that IP to allow more fast requests)